# Python 3 tkinter button command inside different class

Tags: python, class, button, tkinter, function

I'm creating a Python (3.4.3) - tkinter program and am wondering whether it is possible to reference a `def` (self.get_details) from inside another `class` for a button's command. I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem anywhere, so I figured I'd just ask.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
...

class Widgets(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init___(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI():

        # Lots of other different tkinter widgets go here

        self.button = tk.Button(command=App(get_details))
        self.button.pack()


class PopUp(tk.TopLevel): ....

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def get_details(self):

        # Complete a function

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("My Application")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")

        self.pack()

        self.widgets = Widgets(self)
        self.widgets.pack(side="top", anchor="center", fill="both", expand=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.mainloop()
```

So I would like a button which belongs to the class `Widgets()` to call a command that is `def get_details(self)` which belongs to the class `App()`, which has the `Widgets()` class packed inside it.

I hope I was descriptive enough, it is fairly hard to word this problem. I am still kind of new to Python in general. Thanks!

Edit:

As suggested I changed it to `self.parent.get_details()`, which worked! However when I reference a tkinter widget from the `Widgets()` class inside `def get_details()` for example: `self.button`, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'button'
```

So I tried referencing the button as: `self.parent.button`, to which I received:

```
AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'button'
```

How should I be calling/referencing the button? Thanks!

Comment: `self.parent.get_details()` should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: Worked mostly, see edits.

Comment: To reference something from a `Widgets` object while you're in `get_details`, use `self.widgets.button`. Whichever object you're in, `self` refers to an instance of that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `App`, you create a `Widgets` object and save a reference to it named `self.widgets`. When you do so, you pass a reference to that `App` object into the `Widgets` object. That `App` instance reference is saved within the `Widgets` object as `self.parent`. Keep in mind that these two uses of `self` refer to different objects: while in `App`, `self` refers to the current instance of that `App` object. While in `Widgets`, `self` refers to the current instance of that `Widgets` object. To refer to something that's inside the other class, you have to use the proper reference and follow the path.

In an `App` instance:

```
self             this App instance
.widgets         the Widgets instance it contains
.button          the button in that Widget instance
```

In a `Widgets` instance:

```
self             this Widgets instance
.parent          the App object that created this Widgets object
.get_details     the get_details function in the parent App object
```

In the following, I've fixed your code's leftover bits (`...` causing syntax errors, `Style` not defined, etc.) and provided a small example of how to reference each object from the other one. The button initially says "hello", which you can change to "goodbye" by clicking it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Widgets(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # Lots of other different tkinter widgets go here

        self.button = tk.Button(text='hello', command=self.parent.get_details)
        self.button.pack()

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def get_details(self):

        self.widgets.button.config(text='goodbye')

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("My Application")

        self.pack()

        self.widgets = Widgets(self)
        self.widgets.pack(side="top", anchor="center", fill="both", expand=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me so clearly. It's a real help! I tried having the button as `self.widgets.button` however it still gave me the Attribute Error for 'App' again. I then redefined `self.widgets = Widgets(self)` directly above where I was trying to call the object, but that gave me a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. Sorry for being such a pain!

Comment: @jimimatthews, I've added a modified version of your code to demonstrate how to reference the various objects.

Comment: You've been a great help, Thanks heaps for being so patient, you're a legend!