# CustomTkinter TabView button enablement between classes

Tags: python, tkinter, tabview, customtkinter

I have widgets on several tabs and an overall OK button. The OK button is disabled until changes are made to the widgets and a command is called. How do I reference the OK button so that it is a recognised attribute within Entry_Done?

I have tried all sorts of variations of tab_view / app / master but have left the problem area as xxx to avoid clutter.

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class MyTabView(ctk.CTkTabview):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.add('tab 1')

        self.Entry = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=self.tab('tab 1'), values=['', 'Yes', 'No'], command=self.Entry_Done)
        self.Entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

    def Entry_Done(self, *_args):
        self.xxx.OKButton.configure(state='normal')

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_view = MyTabView(master=self)
        self.tab_view.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.OKButton = ctk.CTkButton(self, text='OK', state='disabled')
        self.OKButton.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='ew')

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

I have a feeling I need to define `self.parent` akin to [Python 3 tkinter button command inside different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690365/python-3-tkinter-button-command-inside-different-class) but I haven't been able to get this to work either.

UPDATE: I can get something to work if I move the Entry_Done function down to class App and call it as a command on self.Entry as `command=master.Entry_Done` but I still have a problem as I want to do more stuff before enabling the OK button. So, how can I call Entry_Done with this revised code please?

```
class MyTabView(ctk.CTkTabview):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.add('tab 1')

        self.Entry = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=self.tab('tab 1'), values=['', 'Yes', 'No'], command=self.Do_Stuff)
        self.Entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

    def Do_Stuff(master,  *_args):
        master.Entry_Done() # what to put here?

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_view = MyTabView(master=self)
        self.tab_view.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.OKButton = ctk.CTkButton(self, text='OK', state='disabled')
        self.OKButton.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='ew')

    def Entry_Done(self, *_args):
        self.OKButton.configure(state='normal')
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this works:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class MyTabView(ctk.CTkTabview):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.add('tab 1')

        self.Entry = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=self.tab('tab 1'), values=['', 'Yes', 'No'], command=self.Do_Stuff)
        self.Entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

    def Do_Stuff(self,  *_args):
        App.Entry_Done(self)

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_view = MyTabView(master=self)
        self.tab_view.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.OKButton = ctk.CTkButton(master=self, text='OK', state='disabled')
        self.OKButton.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='ew')

    def Entry_Done(self, *_args):
        self.master.OKButton.configure(state='normal')
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

As well as moving the Entry_Done function to the App class, I have added `self.master` to the OKButton enablement.

Comment: This answer would be a little better if you described what changes you made. Otherwise the reader is forced to compare your code to the OP's line-by-line and character-by-character.